# Understanding a proof that left-semisimple is equivalent to right-semisimple

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory

In Weintraub's *Representation Theory of Finite groups*, he asserts that

> **Corollary 2.18** A ring $R$ is semisimple as a left $R$-module iff it is semisimple as a right $R$-module.
>
> Proof. This follows immediately from Theorem 2.16 and Lemma 2.17.

Here is Theorem 2.16 and Lemma 2.17:

> **Theorem 2.16** Let $R$ be a (**left**) semisimple ring. Then there is a finite set $A$, a collection of integers $\{n_{\alpha}| \alpha \in A\}$, and division rings $\{D_{\alpha}|\alpha \in A\}$ such that $$R\cong \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} \operatorname{End}_{D_{\alpha}}(D_{\alpha}^{n_{\alpha}}).$$
>
> **Lemma 2.17** Let $D$ be a division ring and $n$ a positive integer. Then $ \operatorname{End}_D(D^n)$ is semisimple as a left $\operatorname{End}_D(D^n)$-module and also as a right $\operatorname{End}_D(D^n)$-module. Furthermore, $\operatorname{End}_D(D^n)$ is semisimple as a left $D$-module and also as a right $D$-module.

In my view, to show that $R$ is right (or left) semisimple one has to show $\operatorname{End}_{D_{\alpha}}(D_{\alpha}^{n_{\alpha}})$ is a right (or left) semisimple as a $R$-module. But Lemma 2.17 only considers $\operatorname{End}_{D_{\alpha}}(D_{\alpha}^{n_{\alpha}})$ as a right (or left) $\operatorname{End}_{D_{\alpha}}(D_{\alpha}^{n_{\alpha}})$-module. Can anyone explain the deduction more explicitly for me?

Also, I know that different minimal two-sided ideals of $R$ annihilate each other. It seems this result may help (?). But Weintraub has delayed this result to the next several sections, so I think he does not need it here.

Comment: The missing piece is that the direct sum of semisimple rings is semisimple.

Comment: @DanielArreola Suppose that $R=\oplus S_i$. When each $S_i$ is said to be semisimple, I think one means that $S_i$ is semisimple as an $S_i$-module, not as an $R$-module. But to deduce $R$ is semisimple, I think one has to show that $S$ is semisimple as an $R$-module? That's precisely my quesion.

Comment: You need to show that $R$ is semisimple as an $R$ module. Try to work this out for the direct sum of two rings and then apply induction. If you get stuck I can post a full answer.

Comment: @DanielArreola I think I understand now. Is it by definition of the direct sum of rings that $S_1 S_2 = \{0\}$ in $R = S_1 \oplus S_2$? If so, then each simple $S_i$-submodule of $S_i$ is automatically a simple $R$-submodule, hence $R$ is a direct sum of irreducible submodules.

Comment: That's correct :)

Comment: @DanielArreola Thank you. That is what I get confused from the beginning, as is described in the last paragraph of my question (but I failed to state my confusion clearly). That $S_1$ and $S_2$ annihilate each other is usually a lemma that needs to be proved in most texts on representation theory when paving the way toward Wedderburn decomposition; somehow Weintraub manage to avoid the lemma. I have felt that I had to use this lemma to show that $S_i$-submodules are also $R$-submodules, but since Weintraub never proved it before, I thought he could prove corollary 2.18 without it.

Comment: @DanielArreola I still wonder if there is a proof avoid using the fact that $S_1 S_2 = \{0\}$?